# get APK file from ionic in visual studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get the APK application file IONIC built up in visual studio but got an error. When I click on the "device", he writes to me:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   BLD102  Error : BLD00102 : No such file or directory 'build.template'       IonicCordovaProject1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your coding i think you mentioned "build.template". But the device can't found the file. so link to that file properly then built.